# Check whether the checkbox are checked or not

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, angular8, angular9

I have checkbox in my d3 tree. my code is as follows.

```
 nodeEnter.append('foreignObject').attr('width', '20')
        .attr("x", 200 / 2)
        .attr("y", 1)
        .attr('height', '20').append('xhtml:input')
        .attr('type', 'checkbox')
        // An on click function for the checkboxes
        .on("click",function(d){
            console.log(d)
        });
```

From this code I am able to catch data on click of checkbox. But with this I want to know whether the check box is checked or not. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the click function you can access the node being clicked with `this`, and see if it is checked with `this.checked`

```
.on("click",function(d){
   var check = this.checked;
   console.log(check,d);             
});
```

Alternatively, you can use d3 to achieve the same thing with `d3.select(this).property("checked");` As you are using d3v5 or earlier, you can also access the clicked node as follows:

```
.on("click",function(d,i,nodes){
        var check = nodes[i].checked;
        console.log(check,d);             

    });
```

Here's the first approach:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 300);
  
var data = [1,2];

var nodeEnter = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter();

nodeEnter.append('foreignObject').attr('width', '20')
        .attr("x", (d,i) => i*50+50)
        .attr("y", 1)
        .attr('height', '20').append('xhtml:input')
        .attr('type', 'checkbox')
        // An on click function for the checkboxes
        .on("click",function(d){
            var check = this.checked;
            console.log(check,d);             

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```